# Disable autocompletion on windows tablet keyboard for textbox control in a Windows 8.1 store app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, tablet

I would like to stop my Windows 8.1 Store application's tablet keyboard from providing an autocompletion option when using a textbox

Is there a way to set this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the suggestions then you need to add this to the xaml of the Textbox

```
IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"
```

Giving this result :

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtExample"                                
       Style="{StaticResource TextBoxStyles}"
       IsTextPredictionEnabled="False"/>
```